# Iterate in Big Data Batch jobs (spark jobs)

Tags: talend

I will have 5-6 files on HDFS everyday which I have to parse and load to HIVE tables.

How can I iterate each file to the next component (tfileinputpositional).

I cant fine tfilelist/tloop on Big Data Batch job on Talend studio.
Please help me.

Comment: there is  thdfslist which gives list of files or dir from hdfs. you can check that

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response 
the thdfslist doesnt appear on a Big data batch job.